# GIT alternative to cherry picking

Tags: git, structure

I've the following git structure problem within my team. Our structure is as follow:

**Branches**

- Master (release tags)
- Staging
- Development

And everybody is coding on **development**, and if they wanna push the changes then they cherry-pick their commits to **staging** and then merge **staging** with **master**.

We want to work with feature branches but I don't know how. The problem is.

- We work with a product where we create new custom features with several developers.
- When the feature is done, then it will be pushed to **development** branch and then the client can test it. It is possible to push several features and different client sections need to test. If 1 client section approved the feature then the developer cherry-picked that one feature and push it to **staging**.
- It isn't possible to merge everytime from the **development** to the **staging**, because it contains features that are not allowed on the **staging**.
- It isn't possible that we wait till the feature is tested and then work on another feature, because that cost time, and we need to wait on the client before we can show that feature on **staging**.

**How can we add the following structure**

- Master (release tags)
- Staging
- Development
- feature/*
- hotfix/*

Comment: Testing occurs *before* merges. When a single feature works in its branch, you merge to development to ensure that features continue working *together*. A working snapshot in development is merged to staging to test that you can *deploy*  that set of features correctly. Once you are confident that staging works, *then* you push a new release to production. Note this requires multiple testing environments, ideally environments that you can tear down and rebuild quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work on a feature branch, one per feature, and after submitting it as a PR and reviewing it among the developers, merge it to `development`.

Tell the clients to test. Meanwhile continue working on other feature branches.

When the client approves the feature, *merge the same feature branch* to `staging`. (Even if you have deleted the branch name prematurely, if you used a PR, the branch's last commit remains accessible because the PR exists forever, marking the place.)

Comment: It seems you miss two *possibly* needed points. 1) `development` can|have be merged **to** `feature_branch` (if during work development got independent changes) in order to verify smooth integration at one step earlier 2) After UserTesting of `development` with pre-merged `feature_branch` merge `development` (!!!) from mergeset of `feature_branch` into `staging` (I see more clean and discoverable DAG in *this* style)

Comment: @LazyBadger I regard the entire premise of the question as problematic. I'm merely trying to construct a scenario that satisfies it, i.e. a way to do what they are in fact doing but without saying `cherry-pick`. That is what the OP asked for; the OP did _not_ ask for a better branch architecture! I do not at all think this a good thing _to_ do, I'm just trying to help to the OP do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guy's. A better branch/work-flow structure would be better. So I'll bring this discussion to my team and keep you up-to-date what kind of structure we followed.

Comment: It isn't possible to merge development to testing, because the development branch can contain some work from other feature branches and they can't be merged to staging if they aren't tested.